# Vite build (executed using npm or pnpm) throws RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, vite

I created docker container using docker compose, which builds from image `node:lts-alpine`.

In docker, I would install pnpm and after that, I call `pnpm build`, which in background executes `vite build`.

It ends up with:

```
error during build:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at file:///builder-docker/dev_docker_build/final_build/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.5.0_@types+node@20.8.10_sass@1.69.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:37177:54
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _interpolate (file:///builder-docker/dev_docker_build/final_build/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.5.0_@types+node@20.8.10_sass@1.69.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:37176:18)
    at file:///builder-docker/dev_docker_build/final_build/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.5.0_@types+node@20.8.10_sass@1.69.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:37210:15
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _interpolate (file:///builder-docker/dev_docker_build/final_build/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.5.0_@types+node@20.8.10_sass@1.69.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:37176:18)
    at file:///builder-docker/dev_docker_build/final_build/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.5.0_@types+node@20.8.10_sass@1.69.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:37210:15
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _interpolate (file:///builder-docker/dev_docker_build/final_build/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@4.5.0_@types+node@20.8.10_sass@1.69.5/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:37176:18)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The interesting thing is, when i install vite globally `npm i -g vite` and I run `vite build`, build happens successfully.

I am using `vite@4.5.0`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the only solution that helped with the problem was upgrading vite to `^5.0`. Since version 5, everythings works well.

I tried:

- rebuilding node-sass
- installing rollup-linux-x64-{gnu,musl}
- removing node_modules and reinstalling again
- removing pnpm-lock.json and reinstalling
- trying a few of different docker images